# Chrome browser version - 72.0.3626.121 not opening with selenium

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import init.Constants;

public class TestSelenium {

```
private static WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+Constants.getChromeDriver());
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");

}
```

}

I am getting the error as below

Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628402 (536cd7adbad73a3783fdc2cab92ab2ba7ec361e1) on port 45163
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

The chrome browser is opening but the url is not coming up.

I am using

Chrome driver - 72.0.3626.69

WebDriver - 3.0

Comment: you are missing use of set chrome driver.exe path System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe"); use above the driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: I have provided it - sorry its not there in the above code. Thanks

Comment: please update your question with error stack trace.

Comment: [1554105685.243][INFO]: Launching chrome: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --disable-web-resources --enable-automation --enable-logging --force-fieldtrials=SiteIsolationExtensions/Control --ignore-certificate-errors --load-extension="D:\Users\unccej\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir14196_3309\internal" --log-level=0 --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote

Comment: Why you are using Constant.getChromePath(); ?

Comment: There is Constants class where i am defining the path. Thanks

Comment: @garlapak I have answered your question and I also used Selenium 3.14.0

Comment: @OsandaDeshan - i am using Selenium 3.14 only.

Comment: @garlapak Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can use `bonigarcia` dependency for your automation. Then you don't need to keep `chromedriver.exe` or setting up system variables. It will do all the configurations automatically for all the platforms and all the browsers as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is a sample class to get chrome browser instance. You can modify this class as per your requirement.

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class DriverFactory {

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
         WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
         return new ChromeDriver();
    }


}
```

I have tested this with `Selenium 3.14.0` and `Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned using `Chrome driver - 72.0.3626.69` but error shows `Starting ChromeDriver 2.46.628402`. Check if you have correct chrome driver.

The possible reasons:

- Old selenium (download 3.14.xx from https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- older chrome driver (consider update to the latest chromedriver https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=73.0.3683.68/)
- Chrome browser version mismatch (check the browser version and chromedriver compatibility at https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection)
- Older Java version (latest Java version 11.0.2)

Comment: I am trying all the versions - logs is wrong - but I am using 3.14 - thanks

Comment: What about java version?

Comment: Java version 1.7.0_75 - Thanks

Comment: I guess Java version might be causing the issue. I am using 11.0 and it's working without any issue.

Comment: no luck. looks like something the office network is blocking. Any clue

Comment: Do you mind sharing the url? If it's not private. I can quickly check. And are you using any vpn?

Comment: i am not able to open the www.google.com site only.

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 (3c16f8a135abc0d4da2dff33804db79b849a7c38) on port 39433
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Comment: Here is the complete chromedriver.log

Comment: Are you running it on grid node? Try launching the node in the local machine and check if it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191012/discussion-between-supputuri-and-garlapak).

Answer (score 0):

it does not open because you have not specify the path of the `chromedriver.exe` file

please find the below code snippet.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");

        // Initialize browser
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        // Open facebook
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

        // Maximize browser

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to first set the Chrome driver path before calling the Chrome driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path of the exe file\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set chrome options:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--whitelist-ip *");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Check your browser version with your webdriver version on this page: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Step 2: If after followed above step till you have the same issue then follows the below method:

```cpp
public class TestSelenium {

  private static WebDriver driver;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","user.dir");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
  }
}
```